# How can I segment areas, each of which has nearly same colors of pixels in an image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, image-segmentation, color

For clarity, Nearly same colors of pixels belong to a category. Another nearly same colors of pixels belong to another category. The distinction depends on nearly same RGB values of pixels.

Comment: You need to give us more information (please _edit your question_).  If you burrow down to the bottom of image segmentation, you get to a plain old detection problem: does this pixel belong in category A or category B?  So what distinguishes your almost-same-color pixels from one another, that makes you think they belong in one category or another?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **show** us a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is a GIF (or similar), you have large areas a single colour.
To find where these areas end, an edge detector is the logical choice.

In DSP terms, look at high pass filters to detect changes when you move between areas.

**Note**: jpeg and other picture formats can have areas where colour slowly changes. In this case, the edge between colours is not an easy choice.